# Jquery toggle always open div's / open at start

Tags: toggle, jquery

I'm using the following script to create a toggle effect for opening and closing div's.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mainmenu/js/jquery.min.4.1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
jQuery(".content").hide();
jQuery(".heading").click(function()
{
jQuery(".content").hide();
jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
});
});
</script>


<div class="main_text_faq"
<p class="heading">Header-1 </p>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum</div>
<p class="heading">Header-2</p>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum</div>
<p class="heading">Header-3</p>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Now I can't just seem to figure out how I can let Header 1 to always be open and to have Header 2 open when entering the content.
Any ideas how I can start coding this? I am in the process of learning how to use Jquery so please forgive me for not having anything to show for what I allready tried to fix my "problem"

Thanks in advance.
Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want the first `.content` element to stay visible when the others are initially hidden. To do that you can use the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) pseudo-selectors to exclude the first element:

```
jQuery(".content:not(:first)").hide();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/RhXPC/6/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! This was indeed what I was looking for, thank you for reformulating the original question (English is not my native language). I'm gladd it's actually that simple by using the pseudo-selectors that you provided. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. There should be a tick to the left of my answer which you can click to accept this answer as the correct one as it helped you!